# Render Bitmaps by using SkiaSharp instead of System.Drawing

Tags: c#, wpf, skiasharp, system.drawing.common

With the recent update to Net 6.0 the `System.Drawing.Common` libary is only supported on Windows. In my WPF Application I decided to swap it for SkiaSharp but encountered a problem in the process.

Every information I found about rendering with Skia comes down to using a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and forward it to the UI which as far as I understand, is only supported on Windows.

So my question is how do I render my Images with Skia in Net 6.0 without using `System.Drawing.Common`?

Comment: WPF is only supported on Windows (and always was), so using System.Drawing.Common to forward things to the UI seems fine.

Comment: Little offtopic, but maybe [Avalonia](https://avaloniaui.net/) is an option? It's runs on dotnet and is multi platform WPF like, build on Skia.

Comment: @PMF so you say I should do my Image generation with Skia and forward it to a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` for rendering in the UI? The documentation just states that you should use other libaries but they not describe how exactly and my current (old) code no longer works in 6.0.

Comment: @Mazzelfassel But if I understand you correctly, your GUI is WPF and you're running on Windows? Then everything should still work as before. I have not done many tests with `System.Drawing.Common` on .NET6.0 yet, but that was not deprecated. If you have any problems there, please ask specific questions regarding that part.

Comment: I've found the source of my problem, it was acutally caused by completly different component that was coincidentally related to the same systems that used `System.Drawing.Common` and thus lead me to a wrong assumption, but I would not rule out that they are 100% unrelated. Anyways I still would like to get the warnings out of my editor relating the target platform but my initial problem is resolved for now.